# Read Text file content from External DLL Resource file VB6

Tags: dll, resources, external, loadlibrary

I'm trying to load external text from my custom DLL resource file, but it's not working.

Resource file content (Test.dll, Test.rc and Test.res containing Eula.txt), the Eula.txt file is about 6Kb:

```
900 CUSTOM  "Eula.txt"
```

I'm using the code like this:

```
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long  
Private Declare Function LoadString Lib "user32" Alias "LoadStringA" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal wID As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nBufferMax As Long) As Long  
Private Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long

Public Function LoadStrRes(lgResID As Long) As String  
 On Error Resume Next  

 Dim lgRet As Long  
 Dim stBuff As String * 32768  
 Dim lgBuffPos As Long  
 Dim stFile As String  

 stFile = App.Path & "\Test.dll"  

 lgRet = LoadLibrary(stFile)  

 Call LoadString(lgRet, lgResID, stBuff, Len(stBuff))  

 lgBuffPos = InStr(1, stBuff, Chr$(0))  

 LoadStrRes = Left$(stBuff, lgBuffPos - 1)  

 Call FreeLibrary(lgRet)  

 Exit Function  
End Function
```

Calling the function like this:

```
Dim stTxtData As String  

stTxtData = LoadStrRes(900)  

txtEula.Text = stTxtData
```

Can someone tell my why is it not working for me?

Regards

Comment: Although you've written it twice, you haven't explained what "not working" means. If you can't clearly describe the problem you're having it's difficult to help you, because we can't see your screen or read your mind from where we sit. If you want help, you need to [edit] your question and explain the problem clearly, and then you can ask a more specific question than "why is it not working for me?".

Comment: What was written twice?!? The function returns me empty string, but if I read STRINGTABLE then it's working fine, so, why can't I read CUSTOM data form external resource file with this function?

Answer (score 1):

`LoadString` is described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as being designed to load a *string resource* (meaning a `STRINGTABLE`), not generic RC_DATA or CUSTOM resources. Put your strings in a proper STRINGTABLE as they should be, and it will work to load strings, although you may have issues with storing an entire EULA because of size.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that now, but how can I read then RC_DATA or CUSTOM resources from my external resource file?

Comment: You have to first use FindResource, then call SizeofResource to find out how large, allocate space for it, call LockResource, then LoadResource to actually get the content into the space you've allocated, and then UnlockResource to release it again. I've no idea of how to do that using VB6, I'm afraid; I can do it in a couple of other languages, but not that one. See the [docs for LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It's true, I found it in C++ but I need it for VB6! :( [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994576/how-to-use-a-resource-file-txt-tab-delimited-as-a-data-source-for-win32-appl)